# Set Z-Index Based on Query String

Tags: php, variables, z-index

I have some code that first selects an option value in a dropdown menu based on a query string contained in a link on another page:

```
  <form action="" method="post" name="program" class="program">
  <?php
  $options = array('football1' => 'Football', 'baseball1' => 'Baseball', 'basketball1' => 'Basketball', 'hockey1' => 'Hockey', 'soccer1' => 'Soccer');
  echo '<select name="name" size="1" onchange="ShowHide(this.value);">';
  foreach($options as $clinic => $name) {
    if(array_key_exists('clinic', $_GET) && $_GET['clinic'] === $clinic) {
        echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$clinic.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<option value="'.$clinic.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
   }
  echo '</select>';
  ?>
  </form>
```

What this does is take the referring link, such as `www.mysite.com/sports?clinic=soccer1`, and select the specified option value on the page load. The result is that the dropdown menu cycles through registration forms. The forms are in layered iframes, and when a different clinic is selected, its z-index increases and moves its form to the top. However, I need to edit the following code so that the iframe that initially has the z-index attribute is also based on the referring link:

```
<iframe id="football1" style="z-index:1;" src="www.mysite.com/football"></iframe>
<iframe id="baseball1" src="www.mysite.com/baseball"></iframe>
<iframe id="basketball1" src="www.mysite.com/basketball"></iframe>
<iframe id="hockey1" src="www.mysite.com/hockey"></iframe>
<iframe id="soccer1" src="www.mysite.com/soccer"></iframe>
```

Everything worked fine before because I always had the first item, football1, on top to begin with. But now that people will be coming to specific sports, I need that z-index to be able to start in any of the iframes. I assume it depends on whether the $clinic variable from the dropdown menu is defined. If it is undefined, then the z-index will still default to the first item. If not, it will be attributed to whatever clinic the link came to. I just have no idea how to execute this. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of layering, have you thought of hiding/showing the iframes? This is pretty easy to do in JS, or you can just apply `style="display:none;` to the hidden/background iframes.

Comment: Thanks, Dutchie. I forget why I did it this way in the first place. I might have had a reason, but hiding and showing does sound more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you adapt the same code you use for the `select` dropdown element? The logic is exactly the same:

```
$options = array('football1' => 'Football', 'baseball1' => 'Baseball', 'basketball1' => 'Basketball', 'hockey1' => 'Hockey', 'soccer1' => 'Soccer');
foreach($options as $clinic => $name) {
   if(array_key_exists('clinic', $_GET) && $_GET['clinic'] === $clinic) {
       echo '<iframe id="'.$clinic.'" style="z-index:1;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www.mysite.com/'.$name.'"></iframe>';
   }
   else {
       echo '<iframe id="'.$clinic.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="www.mysite.com/'.$name.'"></iframe>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Julien. That should have been easy enough, but I've been up for 24 hours and I'm not too comfortable with php to begin with. It works great.

Comment: Actually, it works at first, but if you leave the page and come back through the standard link, the dropdown menu option will always be the first value, and it won't necessarily match the form on top. I don't want to add the clinic query string to the regular links that bring users to the page, so I'll have to add another bit of code.

Comment: Well, the code is exactly the same in both cases, so maybe that's your browser "remembering" the last option you selected in the dropdown. In that case a Javascript solution might be more elegant. Or run this to set a default parameter: `if(!array_key_exists('clinic', $_GET)) $_GET['clinic'] = "football1";`

Comment: I think your solution is perfect. I don't see any issues with it. Thanks a lot. By the way, why is your last bit of code slightly different from the line below it (extra ), no &&)?

Comment: ...just one equal sign. Was the original syntax a little wrong?